# Converting SQL ROW_NUMBER to Linq produces wrong translation

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda, entity-framework-core

I have the following SQL code and I want to convert to Linq lambda query in Entity Framework Core 8.

```
SELECT * 
FROM(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StaffId,[Location] ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC) AS rn, 
           StaffId, 
           Location, 
           [Timestamp] 
    FROM CountryStaff 
    WHERE [Timestamp] >= 
            DATEADD(hour,-1, GETDATE())
            AND [Location] = 'USA'
) x  
WHERE x.rn = 1
```

Here's my Linq code.

```
var date = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1);
var filteredTransactions = CountryStaff
    .Where(t => t.Location == "USA" && t.Timestamp >= date)
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.Timestamp);

filteredTransactions
    .OrderByDescending(t => t.Timestamp)
    .Skip(0)
    .Take(1)
    .Select(t => new
    {
        StaffId = t.StaffId,
        Location = t.Location,
        Timestamp = t.Timestamp
    }).ToList();
```

When this code is executed it's translated as follows and produces the wrong result

```
DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = 'USA'
DECLARE @p1 DateTime = '2024-02-28 06:25:22.590'
DECLARE @p2 Int = 0
DECLARE @p3 Int = 1

SELECT [t2].[StaffId], [t2].[Location], [t2].[Timestamp]
FROM (
    SELECT [t1].[StaffId], [t1].[Timestamp], [t1].[Location], [t1].[ROW_NUMBER]
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t0].[Timestamp] DESC, [t0].[Timestamp] DESC) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t0].[StaffId], [t0].[Timestamp], [t0].[Location]
        FROM [CountryStaff] AS [t0]
        WHERE ([t0].[Location] = @p0) AND ([t0].[Timestamp] >= @p1)
        ) AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p2 + 1 AND @p2 + @p3
    ) AS [t2]
ORDER BY [t2].[ROW_NUMBER]
```

***EDIT***

I try to use this code. It runs well although translates different sql query. Unfortunately, it takes 5 seconds instead of 0.6ms.

```
CountryStaff 
    .Where(t => t.Timestamp >= date && t.Location == "USA")
    .GroupBy(t => new { t.StaffId, t.Location })
    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(t => t.Timestamp).First())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: You must group by `StaffId` and `Location` to emulate the partition.

Comment: Just a small question, is a partition by Location even needed, since all Locations are just going to be USA?

Comment: @SMSTJ Yes. Don't get me wrong. USA is not a country. It's a room/building. Within a day, a same staff id can enter many locations

Comment: @derodevil yeah but you have a filter in your where that only accepts USA. So why even Partition for Locations? Also I assume StaffId will be uniqe/the row identifier right?

Comment: Im just confused because the WHERE clause will always run first due to execution order, meaning that it makes no snese to partition/group by it.

Comment: It is not convertible to SQL via EF Core. Use FromSql instead. EF Core generates ROWN_NUMBER for different reason. It is trying to emulate OUTER APPLY to limited recordset via subquery or LEFT JOIN.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv do we need something thats exactly convertable? In my mind we group by StaffId which should always be unique and Location which will alwaus be USA after the were. So dont we just need the where and order by? Isnt the Partition redundant? And if the Ids arent unique cant we just squeeze in a DistinctBy?

`countryStaff
.Where(t => t.Timestamp >= date && t.Location == "USA")
.OrderByDescending(o => o.Timestamp)
.DistinctBy(d => d.StaffId).Select(s => s).ToList();
`

Comment: @SMSTJ, OP experience performance issues. So yes, better to do the same SQL. From which version EF Core supports `DistinctBy`? As I know it doesn't.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Well it does work for me but tbf, in my test case I do have quite some company extension packages, so it might not be "natural". Also as for performance issue, If you get rid of uneeded operations (like grouping stuff by location even though every location is the same) it might improve performance

Comment: Interesting, which package do you use for extending EF Core?

Comment: What is the desired result anyway? The SQL statement only returns *latest*, ie MAX Timestamp per StaffId and Location, not the entire row. That's `SELECT StaffId, Location, Max(Timestamp) FROM ... GROUP BY StaffId,Location`. The LINQ query on the other hand tries to return the latest *row* per StaffId and Location. The LINQ equivalent to the SQL statement is `CountryStaff.GroupBy(g=>{g.StaffId,g.Location}).Select(g=>{g.Key,g.Max(g=>Timestamp));`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv its not a public one, but a company internal one, IF its from the package. TBH I havent taken a look if its due to the package, but if you say that EF doesnt support DistinctBy (which I assumed it would becuase you know...linq) then it will be due to the package

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv and even if it were public itll be phased out anyways since we are trying to get away from EF

Comment: *"we are trying to get away from EF"* and towards what?

Comment: "although translates different sql query" to what?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I assume that LinqToDb has operators to generate the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY...` clause as in OP's original query?

Comment: @GertArnold, yes `linq2db` supports Window functions and this query can be expressed via LINQ.

Comment: @flackoverstow Not really towards something concrete. Basically its away from EF and twoards our own libaries. It does make my life quite difficult from time to time but guidelines are guidelines

Comment: @Charlieface, read my first comment. It is not supported, it is used for emulation OUTER APPLY.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Yes you can get `ROW_NUMBER`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/R0rZrV although not sure why it's generated an unnecessary `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @Charlieface, because you have grouping. EF do what you have requested - group items and get first item of the group. It means `OUTER APPLY/LATERAL` join to limited recordset. Since many database engines do not support such join but support Window Functions, they have decided to convert `OUTER APPLY` to `LEFT JOIN` with `ROW_NUMBER` - it is known technique.

Comment: @Charlieface Can't remember I ever noticed that. To me it looks promising, maybe one day they will find out that they only need the subquery. They keep impressing me by how they continue improving query translation.

Comment: @GertArnold, it is not improving it is downgrade for SQL server ;) OUTER APPLY may perform better. I have made such translation in `linq2db` also, but for providers with supports APPLY joins I do not transform to such construction. Imagine you have very BIG table and for this big table they calculated `ROW_NUMBER` - it is fail.

Comment: @GertArnold They keep impressing me with how they manage to bring out half-baked features. It's 100% *obvious* the join isn't necessary and will cause inefficiency. Same goes for `row <= 1` why not `= 1`?

Comment: *same goes for row <= 1 why not = 1* - it is for supporting `Skip`. Probably don't want to make more `if else` cases.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Perhaps, but it's sloppy, because `= 1` is optimized in many DBMSs.